# Creating files and directories from Servlet

Tags: java, file, servlets, directory

I can't create directory or write to a file.

this return false:

```
String cwd = this.getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath(".");
(new File(cwd + File.separator + 'dir')).mkdir();
```

and this throw exception: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/code/./users/foo/test (Brak dost?pu)`: (access denied)

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(path(user, filename));
out.print(content);
```

I'm running Xubuntu with tomcat. I don't use WAR file only symlink in apps directory. and I'm the owner of the app directory (the same as other files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply set group to tomcat7 for my directory.

```
sudo chown $(whoami):tomcat7 myapp
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify absolute path:

```
(new File('/users/foo/dir')).mkdir();
```

I'd recommend to use [java.home](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) variable for this.

Alternatively you can grant write permissions to the user running java process.

Comment: I updated the question, I want to create file and directory in my app folder. The java.home point to /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre and the owner is root.

Comment: The correct answer is that you should not normally write anywhere except home directory. And it looks like that Xubuntu developers haven't taken that into account. But from my experience I haven't met a linux distro which do this well. (The only one exception is EPEL+Jboss). I will post my best practice as one more answer right now.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately most of distros does not create developer-friendly java runtime environment.

Here is a best practice:

1. Download and install Oracle JDK instead openJDK (At this step you
   probably realize that Ubuntu and debian-based distros sucks at java
   development)
2. Create user:

   ```
   useradd -m -G users -s /bin/bash tomcat
   ```
3. Download the freshest tomcat, unpack it to /opt/tomcat-7.0.x
4. Create symlink:

   ```
   ln -s /opt/tomcat-7.0.x /opt/tomcat
   ```
5. Install rc script (the instructions are valid for RHEL, I have no clue how it is done in Ubuntu):

   ```
   ln -s /opt/tomcat/bin/cacalina.sh /etc/init.d/tomcat7
   chown tomcat /etc/init.d/tomcat7
   chmod +s /etc/init.d/tomcat7
   ```
6. Add this script to autostart:

   ```
   chkconfig tomcat7 on
   ```
7. Start the server

   ```
   service tomcat7 start
   ```

In this environment you will not have the problem that you have because ${user.home} will point to a writable directory.